# Обработка перехода по второй кнопке

Tags: java, android, button

У меня есть окно `Activity` в файле *MainActivity*.
Кнопка перехода на него обрабатывается следующим кодом:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(SecAct);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Решено добавить ещё одну кнопку, ведущую на другое окно `Activity`. Как дописать кнопку `button2`?
Пока работает переход только по одной кнопке. Не могу понять как прописать для второй.

Попробовал вот так :

```
Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button swith2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener();
swith2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

Но не работает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

так же как и делаете для первой кнопки сделайте и для второй

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    swith.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(SecAct);
        }
    });

    swith2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent threActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(threActivity);
        }
    });



        Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ativity4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity4.class);
                startActivity(ativity4);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: при добавлении swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { начинает ругаться хотя код  Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    swith.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(SecAct);
        }
    });

Comment: каким образом ругается? Добавляю switch3, все нормально

Answer (score 0):

при добавлении swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { начинает ругаться хотя код

```
Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    swith.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(SecAct);
        }
    });
```

принял на ура..... может можно обойтись без `swith2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`    без него у меня сейчас код выглядит так но я не проверял работоспособность... хотя отладчик не ругается вот код:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
     swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()      
                    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(SecAct);                                          
                        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

всем спасибо покопался в коде вроде заработало... тока вот беда открывает по 1 кнопке окно активити 1 и по кнопке 2 открывает это же окно активити 1 ... может кто поймет в чем дело подскажет?
вот код на данный момент
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

                    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            Intent SecAct2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity2.class);
                            startActivity(SecAct); 
                            startActivity(SecAct2); 
                                       }
    });

    swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent threActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity2.class);
             startActivity(threActivity);
         }
     });    
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```